# Does anyone have any theories about why voting went up so much recently?

Tags: discussion, voting, recent-activity, participation

**Number of posts has gone down, and number of visits has gone down, yet number of votes has gone up drastically:**

[image]

**Why might this be the case?**

Comment: the total number of votes is low enough that this might very well be a single user going through posts and voting a lot. The large uptick in the last 3 weeks is in the order of ~150 votes *per week*. That means roughly 21 votes per day (20 being the limit of votes per day per user if I remember correctly). Looking at the stats for the number of votes per user, I'm pretty sure this is a single user saturating their daily votes in the last weeks

Comment: @glS why is this a comment rather than an answer? Anyway it's true that someone has voted 600 times this month: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=month. This could explain the differential of about +250 votes per week for the two January data points shown. It seems that user voted 48 times in 2020, which could have contributed to the elevated vote counts in late December, but there was 3 weeks in a row with ~250 more votes than usual, certainly not by a user with only 48 votes in 2020. Also vox populi comes at 40 votes not 20.

Comment: I put it as a comment because I didn't really spend much time double-checking it. You are right the limit is 40, I *was* misremembering. I suppose the same guy doesn't explain the Dec28 peak, but some other user might. A cursory look at the top voters would suggest Adam Z.? ~300 votes this year and another 300 at some points last year, but he's been quite a bit more active recently I think. Maybe someone more agile with the data explorer might be able to pull out more data, but I don't know if the history of votes per user is public (I'd guess not)

Comment: Okay, this trend looked a bit suspicious to me at first but you're right that an increase of about ~250 votes/week is not huge, especially when there's a user that's voted about 600 times this month, and another single user might have been the reason for the increase last month.

Comment: to be honest, it could have also been me voting more than usual in Dec 2020. I had slightly more free time than usual so it's possible. Anyway, it's striking how much single users will impact that graph at this stage. It speaks to the very few people that vote actively on posts (and of course the small volume of active users). I probably account for ~10% of votes in that graph (well before the recent increase, which might however be short lived)

Comment: @gIS hopefully it's not short lived but a continuing trend!

Comment: sure, but I mean if it is caused by a couple of new users it's probably going to level up to a lower level at some point

Comment: I may have contributed to the spike as @gIS suspects. I like going on tours of old questions and answers and I suppose I do vote much since sometimes I bump against the daily limit. I did not expect I'd trip any alarms :-)

Comment: @AdamZalcman Voting a lot is a GOOD THING, not a bad thing. See for example: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/5, https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/5. Please continue to go on those tours and vote on things! I don't think that you were so much the one that "tripped an alarm" as much as the user who voted twice as much as you in the month of January 2021.